# Git, How to make my master mirror my develop branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

After messing up with my git branches a lot, I ended up with a stable develop branch and unstable master. I merged my stable commit of develop branch into master. But still my master is unstable. How to make my master completely replicate/mirror my develop branch?

Comment: Please also consider upvoting [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983229/git-how-to-make-my-master-mirror-my-develop-branch/17983429#17983429) if you think it deserves it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your `master` branch to exactly match your `develop` branch, and you're okay with losing work in `master` that may not be in your `develop` branch, then you can simply do a hard reset on `master`:

```bash
# With master branch checked out
$ git reset --hard develop
```

You can read more about the [`reset` command at the official Linux Kernel Git documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html).

Comment: Is there a command to see the difference between Master and develop branches. `git diff Master..branch` just shows all the differences in one go. But I just want to see the files which are in Master that are not in develop.

Comment: What happens if you reverse it, like `branch..master`? Remember that you could always make a `backup` branch off of `master` and keep that around if you're not sure if there's stuff in there that you still need.  Also, are you using the `--name-status` and/or the `--stat=200` flags? EDIT: I just tried using the `--name-status` flag between branches, if you do `git diff branch..master --name-status`, files in `master` that don't exist in `branch` should show up with `A`, as in "added".